# ¿Cómo establecer una imagen predeterminada para un usuario con Mongoose Y Node.js

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Estoy creando una aplicación con alguna funcionalidad similar a twitter donde el usuario publica texto e imágenes. Quiero darle al usuario una foto de perfil predeterminada en caso de que no tenga una, pero no estoy seguro de cómo hacerlo.

Creé una imagen de esquema donde escribí el siguiente código, pero no sé cómo continuar para que lo que quiero implementar funcione:

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const imageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    photo: { type: Array, default:  ['https://wallpapers-clan.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/cute-pusheen-pfp-1.jpg'] }
});
```

Este es el esquema de usuario que creé:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const {Schema} = mongoose;

const saltRounds = 10;


const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: { type: String, require: true },
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, require: true },
    salt: { type: String, require: true },

    followers: [{
            type: 'ObjectId',
            ref: 'User'
          }],
    following: [{
        type: 'ObjectId',
        ref: 'User'
      }],
    posts: [
      {
        type: 'ObjectId',
        ref: 'Post'
      }
    ]
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html

Comment: Porque photo es un array? se puede tener varias fotos de perfil al tiempo? como se relaciona el image schema con el user schema?